# Dynamic select variables in SQL

Tags: sql, variables, select, dynamic

Is it possible to have a variable number of elements selected in a single SQL statement? For eg. based on the number of parameters that have values, those are selected in the statement. If the statement is:

```
"Select x, y, z from table A where abc='123';"
```

and x, y and z are values being passed over from a previous page. So if only x and z have values then the statement should work like:

```
"Select x, z from table A where abc='123';"
```

and if only x has a value, it should select:

```
"Select x from table A where abc='123';"
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: "x, y and z are values being passed over from a previous page" - what are you talking about? What "previous page"?

Comment: I mean i am using PHP and i want to give the users to select the fields they would like to view so i want the statement to display results based on what the user selects. I will pass these as parameters into the database function to retrieve the results accordingly.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with pure SQL or with an application server or a stored procedure?

Comment: where are you calling your sql statement from? if you are building the sql statement in for example php, then of course you can code up some logic to selectively create a statement based on the values of variables.

Comment: SQL and PHP.. so i will pass in PHP variables. I just want to know how to make the select statement dynamic. can it be done?

Comment: so i have to write the logic in PHP itself? does this mean i will have to write multiple SQL statement and put them within if loops? is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building it from a web page, then just modify the select statement using your code to pass to the SQL server.

If you are doing this in SQL (stored proc or something) and passing in which columns to be selected, then yes, you could build the select statement dynamically as a variable. Then execute the variable. It's possible but NOT recommended.

var statement = "select " + @columns + " from table where abc='123'"
exec @statement

Obviously, use caution if you are using this on a web page to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I am using PHP and mysqli for the database connection.. will the column names be an array or something?

Comment: if you are using php, just use php to dynamically create the statement. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704051/dynamic-sql-queries-in-code-possible

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be to concatenate the SQL statement according to the user's request, or hide columns in code. Trying to do it in an SQL statement is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically building a string of sql, just put some conditional logic in your PHP that looks to see what params were passed in and use the appropriate SQL.